# Reclassifying DEM via Raster Calculator in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, dem, raster-calculator, reclassify, map-algebra

I have a DEM which has min-max values of 85m to 121m. I need to reclassify it so that 85m-90m is 1, 91m-95m is 2, and so on. This is easy to do in the Reclassify tool but what's the expression if I will do it in the Raster Calculator?

For testing, I tried to reclassify the first group (85m-90m). The expression:

```
(("DEM" >= 85) + ("DEM" <= 90))*1
```

returns a boolean raster with values of 2 and 1. That's because the two clauses return true and is added up therefore it's 2 for the True cells, 1 for the False cells.

Comment: Nevermind. I've been using `AND` instead of `&`. The following expression works: `(("DEM" >= 85) & ("DEM" <= 90))*1 + (("DEM" >= 91) & ("DEM" <= 85))*2` and so on. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm

Comment: Int(roundup(DEM/10))